Why do explicit animations work better than implicit animations here? (100 Days of Swift UI: Guess the flag)
I'm working on a project challenge. I've previously made a flag quiz game where there are three buttons made by a ForEach loop with images as flags. The challenge is to animate the flags so that the tapped flag is rotated 360 degrees and the others aren't. I've completed the challenge (and the following challenges) successfully. Here is a chunk my code (I've not used images of flags here for ease):
import SwiftUI

struct FlagImage: View {
    var imageName: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Image(imageName)
            .clipShape(.capsule)
            .shadow(radius: 5)
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var countries = ["Estonia", "France", "Germany", "Ireland", "Italy", "Nigeria", "Poland", "Spain", "UK", "Ukraine", "US"].shuffled()
    @State private var correctAnswer = Int.random(in:0...2)
    
    @State private var scoreTitle = ""
    @State private var showingScore = false
    @State private var score = 0
    @State private var message = ""
    @State private var numQuestionsAsked = 1
    
    @State private var rotDegrees = 0.0
    @State private var notPickedOpacity = 1.0
    @State private var scaling = 1.0

    @State private var whichFlagTapped = 0

    @State private var isGameOver: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            
            
            VStack{

                VStack(spacing: 30){
                    VStack {
                        Text("Tap the flag of")
                            .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
                            .font(.subheadline.weight(.heavy))
                        
                        Text(countries[correctAnswer])
                            .foregroundStyle(.black)
                            .font(.largeTitle.weight(.semibold))
                    }
                    ForEach(0..<3){ number in
                        
                        Button{
                            flagTapped(number)
                            whichFlagTapped = number
                            withAnimation {
                                rotDegrees += 360
                                notPickedOpacity -= 0.75
                                scaling -= 0.2
                            }
                        } label: {
                            Color(.red).frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                            Text(countries[number])
                            
                        }.rotation3DEffect(
                            whichFlagTapped == number ? .degrees(rotDegrees) : .degrees(0),
                            axis: (x:0.0, y:1.0, z:0.0)
                        )
                        .opacity(whichFlagTapped == number ? 1.0 : notPickedOpacity)
                        .scaleEffect(whichFlagTapped == number ? 1.0 : scaling)
                    }
                    
                    
                    
                }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                 .padding(.vertical, 20)
                 .background(.regularMaterial)
                 .clipShape(.rect(cornerRadius: 20))
                 
                
                
                Text("Score: \(score)").foregroundStyle(.white).font(.title.bold())
                
                Spacer()
            }.padding()
            
            
        }.alert(scoreTitle, isPresented: $showingScore) {
            Button("Continue", action: askQuestion)
        } message: {
            Text(message)
        }
        .alert("Game Over!", isPresented: $isGameOver) {
            Button("Restart", action: reset)
        } message: {
            Text("\(score) out of 8")
        }
    }
    func flagTapped(_ number: Int){
        if number == correctAnswer {
            scoreTitle = "Correct!"
            score += 1
            message = "Well done! Your score is: \(score)"
        } else {
            scoreTitle = "Wrong!"
            message = "That is the flag of \(countries[number]). \n Your score is: \(score)"
        }
        showingScore = true
    }
    func askQuestion(){
        if numQuestionsAsked < 8 {
            countries.shuffle()
            correctAnswer = Int.random(in: 0...2)
            numQuestionsAsked += 1
            notPickedOpacity = 1.0
            scaling = 1.0
        } else {
            isGameOver = true
        }
    }
    
    func reset() {
        score = 0
        numQuestionsAsked = 0
        askQuestion()
    }
}


While this works fine with explicit animation, I'm trying to figure out why it works better than with implicit animation. Here is what I've got in the loop for implicit animation (focusing only on the rotation this time).
ForEach(0..<3){ number in
                        
                        Button{
                            flagTapped(number)
                            whichFlagTapped = number
                                rotDegrees += 360
                        } label: {
                            FlagImage(imageName: countries[number])
                        }.rotation3DEffect(
                            whichFlagTapped == number ? .degrees(rotDegrees) : .degrees(0),
                            axis: (x:0.0, y:1.0, z:0.0)
                        )
                        .animation(.default, value: rotDegrees)
                    }

In this case, the tapped answer does rotate by 360 degrees when tapped (sometimes more?), but the previous answer also rotates back to 0.
So I'm wondering, why is it that in the explicit animation case this rotation back to 0 does not happen? Or maybe the flag's rotation is actually set to 0 (and not animated since it is only animating the change of rotDegrees?) - but in this case shouldn't picking the flag in that position later on cause it to rotate by some multiple of 360 back up to rotDegrees? Since then the flag's rotation will need to be animated from 0 up to the new rotDegrees? I think I'm missing something important about explicit animation here.

Consider the concept of a [mcve]. Right now there are way too many unknowns in the sliver of code you have shown. If you want help, show enough code that we can actually compile and run that code.

@matt sorry about that. added enough code for people to get a better idea now.

This is simply because you did not put whichFlagTapped = number in the withAnimation closure. If you put that in, the behaviour would be the same - the previously-selected flag rotates back to 0 degrees.
The implicit animation .animation(.default, value: rotDegrees) animates all the changes in the transaction whenever rotDegrees changes. When you press the button, rotDegrees changes, but so does whichFlagTapped == number for the previously-selected button! whichFlagTapped == number would change to false for that button. As a result, for the previously-selected button, its rotation would animate from .degrees(rotDegrees) to .degrees(0).
This is also why it sometimes animates more than 360 degrees. You keep increasing rotDegrees by 360 every time, so for the later questions, when whichFlagTapped == number changes, it would be animating the angle from 0 to n * 360 degrees.
With an explicit animation, you can precisely control which changes are animated. You put whichFlagTapped = number outside withAnimation, so the change of whichFlagTapped == number to false is not animated. The only animation is the increase of rotDegrees by 360.
For a similar situation, see this other answer of mine.
